# Creating a JavaScript global array with static elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, static-array

Creating a JavaScript global array with static elements?

Comment: *"It's really annoying in JavaScript that any changes I make to a global array inside a function won't exist outside that function..."* It certainly *would* be annoying, if it were remotely true. It isn't.

Comment: how is your array global? it looks like you are declaring it in your `.ajax` function???

Comment: You're probably declaring "bigArray" inside your Ajax code with `var`, which makes it a local variable, not global.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to wait.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not seeing the async aspect, either. He says he's waiting for a click, and splicing the value out of the array. He doesn't say he's making another server call. (It's unclear, though, why the splice is shown as pseudo-code rather than code.)

Comment: Please see my EDIT. I thought it was obvious that I was declaring the array globally.

Comment: *"OK, fine, here's my code:"* Nice attitude. Really encourages people to help you.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I think that ship has sailed.

Comment: @AzzyDude: Have you missed that I'm trying to help you?

Comment: haha, actually I did. Didn't read the username between here and your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that `removeFunction` doesn't have access to `bigArray`. The problem is in your `onclick` attribute, and the `id` you're putting on the link:

```
$('#div').append("<a href='#' id='bigArray[i]' onclick='removeFunction(bigArray[i])'>Element bigArray[i]</a><br />");
```

In the `onclick`, you're referring to `i`, but A) I'm guessing `i` isn't a global, and B) Even if it is, it will not have the value of `i` that you used to render that row. The code will look for the value of a global `i` variable **as of when the link is clicked**.

Separately, you're creating multiple elements with the same `id` value, which is `bigArray[i]` (not `bigArray[0]`, `bigArray[1]`, etc.)

You could use the value instead, like this:

```
$('#div').append("<a href='#' id='bigArray[" + i + "]' onclick='removeFunction(" + i + ")'>Element bigArray[i]</a><br />");
```

The changes there are:

- For the `id`, I changed it to: `"...id='bigArray[" + i + "]'"`, which will output `id='bigArray[0]'`, then `id='bigArray[1]'`, etc., instead of repeatedly outputting `id='bigArray[i]'` (literally.
- I just pass the index into `removeFunction`, again by putting the *value* there, not a reference to the variable `i`: `"... onclick='removeFunction(" + i + ")' ..."`

Then your `removeFunction` would be:

```
function removeFunction(i) {    // <== i, not id
    bigArray.splice(i, 1);      // <== real code, not pseudocode
    renderArray(bigArray);
}
```

I would not recommend doing it that way, but it's the minimal fix.

There's no need to pass `bigArray` to anything. It's a global.

---

FWIW, I would recommend refactoring so you don't have to re-render the whole thing every time.

Comment: Yeah, so you've got it there. I don't want to pass the big long array through the onclick function. But I can't think of a better way to do it. You say it's global, but if I try splice an element out of it in the removeFunction function, it says the Array is empty, when it's definitely not.

Comment: @AzzyDude: First off: Passing an array into a function doesn't copy all of its elements, so the size of the array is irrelevant. It just passes a reference. Secondly: I'd missed something which I've justed edited to correct.

Comment: I meant each element in my HTMl would have the whole array in it so it could be passed to the function onclick. 

<a onclick="foo(["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", etc., etc., etc.])"></a>

Comment: @AzzyDude: Certainly no need for that. Did you see my points above? Did you have further questions?

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable at the global scope first that will hold your "bigArray", then assign the value to it once you receive the data through your ajax call.

```
var bigArray;

$.ajax({
    bigArray = bigArrayFromAjax;
    renderArray(bigArray);
});
```

... then your other functions should have access to it.

Comment: The code as presented falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and so the other functions have access to it anyway.

Comment: Your comments are extremely poetic. I like it.

Comment: The problem with this, is for this to work, when I render each element to the page, I will have to pass the ENTIRE array into the HTML for each element.

Comment: So that when you click on the element in the HTML, it can pass the array to the desired function.

Comment: @AzzyDude: No. The whole point is that globals are **global**. You don't have to pass them around. That's their power (and their problem).